# How to apply the same `analysis_options.yaml` to a set of sibling Flutter projects?

Tags: flutter, dart, lint

We have a product that incorporates multiple apps. Roughly looks like this:

- core
- ui_kit
- app1
- app2
- app3

Up till Flutter 3 the solution we used was:

1. Have an `analysis_options.yaml` in the `core` package which contains the actual rules.
2. Have another `analysis_options.yaml` in the very root which contains only:

```
include: core/analysis_options.yaml
```

Now this got transitively applied to every project there is in this folder.

Since Flutter 3 I get this warning:

> The include file 'package:lint/analysis_options.yaml' in '<root_folder>/core/analysis_options.yaml' can't be found when analyzing '<root_folder>'.
> Kinda requesting the root folder to also have `lint` as dependency, which it does not have. Regardless of this the rules from `lint` package are still applied.

Now I can "fix" this by adding `include_file_not_found: ignore` into the main yaml, but is hardly elegant.

Any tips?

Comment: It sounds like `core/analysis_options.yaml` includes `package:lint/analysis_options.yaml` but that the corresponding `pubspec.yaml` file doesn't list `lint` as a dependency.  Can you add it?

Comment: yeah, but I'd prefer the root folder not to be an actual "project"

Comment: Although you prefer not to have one,the reality is that you should have a `pubspec.yaml` file.  Without it, you can't specify which version of `package:lint` you want to depend on. You can create a minimal `pubspec.yaml` file and use `publish_to: none`.